# How to set text of android button in onCreate Method?

Tags: java, android, button, oncreate

I want to set the text of my button in onCreate Method, but it doesn't work.

Code in MainActivity-Class:

```
Button button;
```

Code in onCreate:

```
button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("test");
```

Butto in xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
        android:onClick="checkPermissions"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Here's the Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on
> a null object reference

I know that I can set the text of button in XML, but I want to set the text at app start via sharedpreferences, but it won't work if I can't even set a simple string onto it by calling this easy way.

Comment: did you call `setContentView(your_layout.xml)` first? Otherwise no view is inflated to your activity and `findViewById` can't find anything.

Comment: Yes, but the button is not in activity_main.xml. It is in fragment_recording.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find id fragment you need view reference.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button button= view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setText("text");

    }
```

Comment: Where do I have to put this method?

Comment: @OSbOoL in your fragment

Comment: Thank you very very much. This i what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You better share the whole `onCreate()` code in order to get help.

By now, I could assume you don't call
`setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_with_button)` in `onCreate()` method before accessing button by calling `findViewById(R.id.button)`.

Whole code inside `onCreate()` will be looking smth like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_with_button)

        val button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        button.setText("test")
    }
```

Comment: The onCreate is ok, the Button is in another fragment than in activity_main.xml. Can this be the mistake? But how can I get access to my button then? If I type "R.id." then my button was showing....